Is it possible to have menuItems in a sidebarLayout?
I have a sidebarLayout dashboard and the different inputs are getting messy. I would like to put them under 3 different menuItems as in the pictures below.

Is it possible somehow in the code below?
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput("A", "A", choices = LETTERS[1:5]),
      pickerInput("B", "B", choices = LETTERS[1:5]),
      pickerInput("C", "C", choices = LETTERS[1:5]),
      pickerInput("D", "D", choices = LETTERS[1:5]),
      pickerInput("E", "E", choices = LETTERS[1:5]),
      pickerInput("F", "F", choices = LETTERS[1:5]),
      
      textInput("G", "G"),
      textInput("H", "H"),
      textInput("I", "I"),
      textInput("J", "J"),
      textInput("K", "K"),
      
      numericInput("L", "L", 1),
      numericInput("M", "M", 1),
      numericInput("N", "N", 2),
      numericInput("O", "O", 3),
      numericInput("P", "P", 4),
      numericInput("Q", "Q", 4)
      
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


bslib::accordion_panel is also worth mentioning in this context.

You could try using collapsible panels or accordions. For accordion panels, check out shinydashboardPlus::accordion(). Alternatively, here's an example using collapsible panels in shinyBS.
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      bsCollapse(
        id = "collapsedMenus",

        bsCollapsePanel(
          "Picker Settings",
          pickerInput("A", "A", choices = LETTERS[1:5]),
          pickerInput("B", "B", choices = LETTERS[1:5]),
          pickerInput("C", "C", choices = LETTERS[1:5]),
          pickerInput("D", "D", choices = LETTERS[1:5]),
          pickerInput("E", "E", choices = LETTERS[1:5]),
          pickerInput("F", "F", choices = LETTERS[1:5]),
          style = "primary"
        ),
        bsCollapsePanel(
          "Text Settings",
          textInput("G", "G"),
          textInput("H", "H"),
          textInput("I", "I"),
          textInput("J", "J"),
          textInput("K", "K"),
          style = "success"
        ),
        bsCollapsePanel(
          "Numeric Settings",
          numericInput("L", "L", 1),
          numericInput("M", "M", 1),
          numericInput("N", "N", 2),
          numericInput("O", "O", 3),
          numericInput("P", "P", 4),
          numericInput("Q", "Q", 4)
        )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)


